# Creating constant value in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to create a constant variable inside a keras model. What I was doing till now is to pass it as Input. But it is always a constant so I want it as a constant.(The input is `[1,2,3...50]` for each example => so I use `np.tile(np.array(range(50)),(len(X_input)))` to reproduce it for each example)

So for now I had:

```
constant_input = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32', name="constant_input")
```

Which gives a tensor: `Tensor("constant_input", shape(?,50), dtype=int32)`

Now trying to do it as a constant:

```
np_constant = np.array(list(range(50))).reshape(1, 50)
tf_constant = K.constant(np_constant)
tensor_constant = Input(tensor=tf_constant, shape=(50,), dtype='int32', name="constant_input")
```

which gives a tensor: `Tensor("constant_input", shape(50,1),dtype=float32)`

But What I want is the constant to be scaled in each batch, meaning that the shape of the tensor should be `(?, 50)`, the same as the way of using `Input`.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a constant with variable size. A constant always has the same value. What you can do is have the `(1, 50)` constant and then tile it within TensorFlow with [`K.tile`](https://keras.io/backend/#tile). Also better use [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) instead of `np.array(list(range(50))`. Something like:

```
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
import keras.backend as K

def operateWithConstant(input_batch):
    tf_constant = K.constant(np.arange(50).reshape((1, 50)))
    batch_size = K.shape(input_batch)[0]
    tiled_constant = K.tile(tf_constant, (batch_size, 1))
    # Do some operation with tiled_constant and input_batch
    result = ...
    return result

input_batch = Input(...)
input_operated = Lambda(operateWithConstant)(input_batch)
# continue...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems that it creates the desired dimensions but when I call the `Model()` it gives an error of `Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor `. I am not sure if its related to this or because I am trying to create two `Models`. When using `Input`(1st method described in the question) this error does not occurre.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris Right, I suppose you would have to put the operation into some layer like a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) or something, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you update that answer by doing Dot() with `tiled_constant` and `input_batch`. The resulting tensor should be `(?, 1)` if I am not mistaken. However I cannot get this to work.