# How add scalar to tensor in Keras or create tensor from scalar?

Tags: keras, keras-layer, coreml, coremltools

I need to somehow run someting like that:

```
x = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, img_channels))
x1 = Add()([x, 127.5])
x2 = Multiply()(x1, -127.5])
```

But, error emerges:
`ValueError: Layer add_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'float'>. Full input: [<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 400, 300, 3) dtype=float32>, 0.00784313725490196]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.`

I can't use `Lambda()` layer, because I need to convert final model into CoreML and I'll be unable to rewrite them in swift.

Is there any way to create Keras tensor from float?
Maybe there is a different solution for this problem?

UPD: backend is TensorFlow

Comment: If you can't use a Lambda layer (I don't understand why), I'm afraid you'll need to use a second Input for the constant (or create a custom layer just for the addition)

Comment: Agreed... when using Keras, you can't escape one of these: 1 - Use lambda; 2 - create custom layer; 3 - use a tf tensor as an additional `Input`.

Comment: Note that you can pass these normalization operations to coremltools, so you don't actually have to put them into the Keras model. See also http://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on comments above I've tested 2 approaches. Custom layer was not an option, because I would need to write it in swift for conversion to CoreML model (and I do not know swift).

**Additional input**
There is no way to predefine input value, as far as I know, so I need to pass additional parameters on input, which is not very convinient.
Consider example code below:

```
input1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), tensor=t_b, name='11')
input2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
input3 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), tensor=t_a, name='22')

# x1 = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(input1)
# x2 = keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(input2)

added = keras.layers.Add()([input1, input3])  # equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])
added2 = keras.layers.Add()([input2, added])  # equivalent to added = keras.layers.add([x1, x2])

# out = keras.layers.Dense(4)(added2)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input1, input2, input3], outputs=added2)
```

If you will load that model in clean environment, than you actually will need to pass a 3 values to it: `my_model.predict([np.array([1]), np.array([1]), np.array([1])])` or error will emerge.

**CoreML tools**
I was able to achieve desirable effect by using `*_bias` and `image_scale` parameters in importer function. Example below.

```
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(
    model_path,
    input_names='image',
    image_input_names='image',
    output_names=['cla','bo'],
    image_scale=1/127.5,  # divide matrix by value
    # substract 1 from every value in matrix
    red_bias=-1.0,  # substract value from channel
    blue_bias=-1.0,
    green_bias=-1.0
)
```

If somebody knows how to predefine constant in Keras, which should not be loaded via input layer, please write how ([tf.constant() solution is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932973/how-to-give-a-constant-input-to-keras)).

Comment: Do you mean constant or scalar tensor? I want trainable scalar.

Comment: @mathtick I do not remember, it was too long ago)